# How to call jqueryui autocomplete in masterpage for control defined in content page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, master-pages, content-pages

I am trying to fire the autocomplete jQueryUi widget on a textbox defined in an aspx content page.

My reference to the jQuery-ui.js file is in the head section of the masterpage.

The autocomplete call is made in a script block in the masterpage at the bottom of the page.

I understand the id of the control defined in the content page is different to the id generated in the output page and so the reference I've made to the control (in the script section of the masterpage) is the correct id as it displays in the output page (ctl00_Content_txtEmailAddress_txtText).

I am getting the following exception when the page loads.  Any help, much appreciated.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function 
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (PasswordReset.aspx?r=P1.WEBGUEST&f=P1.EPR.USERPASS.VIW:376)
at fire (jquery.js:974)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1084)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:406)
at HTMLDocument.DOMContentLoaded (jquery.js:83)
```

I've included snippets of the content and masterpage below

Content page:

```
<p1:CustomisableTextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" SkinID="Block" 
Mandatory="true" MandatoryValidation="true" CanDisable="false" 
CanChangeMandatory="false" />
```

Masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ctl00_Content_txtEmailAddress_txtText").autocomplete({
            source: 'AutocompleteHandler.ashx'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've thought a lot about this query I've had and it occurred to me that if autocomplete is not defined, then there must be an issue with the js file that provides the widget.
I've put it down to a couple of things.

1. The file is not being loaded
2. There is an issue/confict between the jquery-ui file and the jquery file
3. There is an issue with the sequence in which the jquery file(s) are loaded into the browser
4. The code block that calls the autocomplete function is incorrectly placed in the masterpage.

Funnily enough, I tried several permutations of each of the above and finally got the file to load without error.
Only problem is the autocomplete doesn't fire !!!
I'll post again when I resolve this issue entirely and hope this helps someone the grief and wasted time it has given me.